# Calculate Orders on a weekly and monthly basis in php

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I need to calculate orders on a weekly and month basis. The code that I have setup so far is like so:

```
foreach ($commissions as $c) {
    $ts = strtotime($c['order_date']);

    $lastWeekKey = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('last monday', $ts));
    $nextWeekKey = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('next sunday', $ts));

    $stringDays = $lastWeekKey." to ".$nextWeekKey;

    if (!isset($dates[$stringDays])) {
        $dates[$stringDays] = 0;
    }
    $dates[$stringDays] += $c['projected_payment'];
}
```

The problem here is that if the date falls on a Monday, then it gets last Monday and the next Sunday. I need it to count that Monday, not the next. The same will go for the month as well. In all, I am just looking for the most accurate and simplistic answer. It does not have to be in the format. For both monthly and weekly.

Comment: Have you looked at the examples on the manual page for [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)?

Comment: Checkout the different formatting parameters the `date` function offers. Then please explain why each of them all are not fitting. If there is a single one (and as you might guess, there is one ;)) that is fitting, name it as well. Congratulations in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With your existing code, you can just add an if statement before you define your Key's. IE:

```
$thisday=getdate($ts);
if($thisday==1) { //1 = Monday
    $lastWeekKey = date("Y-m-d",  strtotime('today',$ts));
    $nextWeekKey = date("Y-m-d",  strtotime('next sunday',$ts));
} else {
    $lastWeekKey = date("Y-m-d",  strtotime('next monday',$ts));
    $nextWeekKey = date("Y-m-d",  strtotime('next sunday',$ts));
}
```

You might have to check that "today" is the actual textual representations for the current day.

Answer (score 0):

if you use mysql you can let the sql do a lot of work.

```
$x = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mysales` 
             WHERE `MerchantID`=’$id’
             AND `Saledate`  > ’TIMESTAMP(".strtotime(’-1 week’).")’");
```